# How to store a value that comes from a for

Tags: java, for-loop, sum

Hi Im new to Java Im trying to make a counter. What Id like to do is calculate the numbers from 1 to x, for example if x is 5, calculate 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5.

This is what I wrote, but I get 6 as output instead of 15.

```java
public class Counter {

     public int count (int x){
         int contatore = 0;
         int sum = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
             sum = i;
             System.out.println(i);
         }
         System.out.println(sum);
        return sum;
     }
}
```

Comment: you are not adding `i` to `sum`, you are setting `sum` to whatever `i` is, try `sum += i`

Comment: Is this an exercise in using loops, or are you looking for an efficient solution to the problem? Because you can get the sum of numbers from 1 to x with `(x * (x + 1)) / 2`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `i` to the sum in each iteration of the loop:

```java
public int count (int x) {
    int contatore = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
        sum += i;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the loop variable to the sum - you need to add it to the sum

```
 public int count (int x){
     int sum = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
         sum = sum + i;
     }
    return sum;
 }
```

As others have noted, you can use the following shorthand notation for addition with assignment.

```
sum += i; // equivalent to sum = sum + i;
```